# Build streaming server for Spotify

Tags: spotify

I would like to develop application similar to github's play. It should be mainly a spotify stream server where every team member can listen to the same music and control the stream for everyone. I'm not sure how would that work in terms of user licenses. Preferably I'd see it as spotify radio that everyone can tune into and everyone can control (or the ones with permissions but all is fine for us)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at Soundrop(http://soundrop.fm/) and their Spotify app? Seems like this is what you want, or a variant of it. Check it out for an idea of how you can create a "radio station" within the limitations of the Spotify apps API.